# Is it possible to portably define a function that accepts any number of arguments?

Tags: c, function, arguments, portability

I have a vague understanding of what 'C portability' means (IIRC, it means that the C language spans multiple platforms, but must adhere to certain standards (?)) and would like to know if we can portably write programs that would accept any number of arguments (even none).

What I do know is that without considering portability, all functions written with an empty pair of parentheses '()' can accept x-amount of arguments, but what about with it? It seems that there are a few papers on encouraging limitations regarding the number of arguments accepted by portably defined functions but I have yet to find one that says we cannot pass x-number of arguments (where is x is not bounded).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- a function **defined** with an empty set of parenthesis:

  void f() {...}

accept no parameters and it is undefined behavior to call it with any.

- a function **declared** with an empty set of parenthesis:

  void g();

must be called with the same number and same type of parameters that it has been defined, but the compiler won't check it. It is an undefined behavior if you mess up.

- to declate a function as taking no parameter (and thus getting an error message if you mess up), use

  void g(void);
- a function may be variadic, but to call it you must see a declaration which state the function is variadic:

  void h(int nb, ...);

(Not that in C a variadic function must have at least one non variadic parameter, in C++ it isn't the case)  A variadic function must be called with at least the non variadic argument specified.

The minimum limit on the number of parameters (for any function) is 127.  (Well, what the standard says is that an implementation must be able to compile at least one program reaching that limit).

--

To clear up a confusion:

```
void f() { ... }
```

vs

```
void g(void) { ... }
```

`f` is defined as accepting no parameters and can't be called with any by declared as accepting an unknow number of parameters so the compiler will not ensure that no paramaters are given.  `g` is defined and declared as accepting no parameters.  It's a left over of K&R days with functions definitions like

```
int h()
    int i;
{...}
```

which declares a function taking an indeterminate number of parameters but define it as taking one int parameter.  This style is totally out of fashion and the only case of practical importance remaining is the f vs g one.

Comment: Regarding just the first part of your answer, I learned that defining a function with an empty set of parentheses could take x-amount of args and that including a void (ex. function(void)) would make it so that it could not accept any. Is that wrong? =/

Comment: Ah I must have misunderstood x.x My apologies! Thank you, this is just what I needed.

Comment: "an implementation must be able to compile at least one program reaching that limit" - it just occurred to me, for this limit there's a serious weasel that an implementation could perform. It could permit up to 127*4 *bytes* of varargs params, and it would satisfy the requirement that one program with 127 compiles - specifically if they're all `int`, but not if they're all `double`. There's even a reason to do it, if for some lazy reason the implementation wanted to throw a fixed size frame onto the stack when doing a varargs call. Hopefully no implementation would stoop so low...

Comment: @Steve, I prefer the C++ approach on this kind of limits: not making it a requirement for conformance but still states desirable minimum. An implementation for limited target will probably not (and should not) take costly workaround for just formal conformance on such points.

Comment: @AProgrammer: it's a difficult compromise, I think. You don't want implementations to claim "formal conformance" if they only support up to 1 vararg in a call. You'd rather they just gave a list of conformance failures including "we don't do varags right". Since, unlike Java, nobody has to put a "passed the tests!" sticker on their compiler, I think a 127 conformance limit isn't so bad, it just means if you do less than that you should say in the documentation that it's a failure in your conformance. Clearly the 127 could be lower, though: only being able to pass 63 doubles wouldn't be so bad.

Comment: ... and anyway this list of specific limits always runs up against other resource limits of the implementation. If someone writes a program that buts up to a whole bunch of them, and says "this is a strictly conforming program, it must work on your compiler", then they're just wrong, it can fail to compile, or run out of stack and get killed at runtime, due to the limitations that the standard leaves unspecified.

Comment: @Steve, The implementation can also state "this is not the program we support for that limit".  That's why I think C formulation is useless. Less than that when you get warnings about extern identifier with more that 6 characters (I know, that limit was raised in C99).

Answer (score 2):

Use `<stdarg.h>`.

See, for example, section 15, question 4 of the [C-FAQ](http://c-faq.com).

---

**Edit**: example of `stdarg.h>` usage

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* sum all values (no overflow checking) up to a 0 (zero) */
int sum(int v, ...) {
  va_list va;
  int s = v;
  if (v) {
    va_start(va, v);
    while ((v = va_arg(va, int))) {
      s += v;
    }
    va_end(va);
  }
  return s;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("sum(5, 4, 6, 10) is %d\n", sum(5, 4, 6, 10, 0));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link! Could you offer more detail on the connection between portability and the number of arguments accepted by a function? I saw a tidbit that mentioned 'so-and-so was important for portability' but it did not explain why.

Comment: As [AProgrammer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/136208/aprogrammer) [says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322958/is-it-possible-to-portably-define-a-function-that-accepts-any-number-of-arguments/5323069#5323069), the limit is 127.

Comment: I see! I think I got confused between the case with considering portability and the case without. Thanks. :)

Comment: @honeywind If your code conforms to the C standard, it will be portable to any conforming implementation of C ... the example above is so portable. But in practice, one needs to go beyond that because there are many requirements that cannot be solved by strictly conforming C programs. Writing practical portable C code is a demanding technical skill and many books and articles have been written about it.